# Use $function (javascript) in mongo repository @Aggregation pipeline

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I have the below query that runs fine in mongo shell. I have to use this from my spring boot java application.

```
 db.UserGames.aggregate([
                        { $match: {$and: [{timestamp: {$gte : ISODate("2021-12-14T09:34:51.000Z"), $lte: ISODate("2022-12-31T09:34:51.000Z")}}]}}, 
                        { $sort:  {timestamp: 1  }},
                        { $group: {
                                   _id: {"userId" : "$userId", "username" : "$username"},
                                    docs: { $push: { win: "$win", timestamp: "$timestamp" } }
                                  }
                        },
                        {$project: {_id:1, docs:1, noOfGames: {$size: "$docs"}}},
                        {$match: {"noOfGames": {$gt: 1}}},
                        {$project: {_id:1, docs:1}},
                        {$addFields: { losingStreak : {
                                            $function: {
                                                body: function(docs) {
                                                            let longestStreak = 0;
                                                            let currentStreak = 0;
                                                            docs.forEach(element => {
                                                                if(element.win < 0) {
                                                                    currentStreak = currentStreak + 1;
                                                                    if(longestStreak < currentStreak) {
                                                                        longestStreak = currentStreak;
                                                                    } 
                                                                } else {
                                                                    currentStreak = 0;  
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                            return longestStreak;
                                                        },
                                                args: ["$docs"],
                                                lang: "js"
                                        }}}},
                        {$project: {_id:1, losingStreak:1}},
                        {$match: {"losingStreak": {$gt: 0}}},
                                    { $sort:  {"losingStreak": -1  }}
                        ], { "allowDiskUse" : true })
```

I have used ReactiveMongoRepository and @Aggregation annotation as below:

```
public interface MyRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<UserGameDetails, Object> {
    
    @Meta(allowDiskUse = true)
    @Aggregation(pipeline = {
            "{ $match: {$and: [{'timestamp': {$gte : ?0, $lte: ?1 } } ] } }",
            "{ $sort:  {'timestamp' : 1 }}", 
            "{ $group: { _id: {'userId' : '$userId', 'username' : '$username'},"
            + " docs: { $push: { 'win': '$win', 'timestamp': '$timestamp' } } } }", 
            "{ $project: {_id : 1, docs : 1, noOfGames: {$size: '$docs'}}}", 
            "{ $match: {'noOfGames': { $gt: ?2 } } }",
            "{ $project: {_id : 1, docs : 1 } }",
            "{ $addFields: { losingStreak : { $function: { "
            + "body: function(docs) { "
            + "let longestStreak = 0; "
            + "let currentStreak = 0; "
            + "docs.forEach(element => { "
            + "if(element.win < 0) { "
            + "currentStreak = currentStreak + 1; "
            + "if(longestStreak < currentStreak) { "
            + "longestStreak = currentStreak; "
            + "}  "
            + "} else { "
            + "currentStreak = 0;  "
            + "}  });"
            + " return longestStreak;  "
            + "}, "
            + "args: ['$docs'], "
            + "lang: 'js' }}}}",
            "{ $project: {_id : 1, losingStreak : 1 } }",
            "{ $match: {'losingStreak' : { $gt : ?2 } } }",
            "{ $sort:  {'losingStreak': -1  } }"})
    
    Mono<List<UsersScores>> getLosingStreakForAllGames(LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime, int minValue);
}
```

But it fails with below error. This error is coming from the java script function inside the query. How can I run this query from my Java Application?

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a name but found '('.
Caused by: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a name but found '('.
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:227)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:360)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:360)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:360)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.captureExpressionDependencies(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ReactiveStringBasedAggregation.computePipelineStage(ReactiveStringBasedAggregation.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.ReactiveStringBasedAggregation.lambda$computePipeline$2(ReactiveStringBasedAggregation.java:132)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:189)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen.subscribe(FluxUsingWhen.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4232)
    at com.dangalgames.leaderboard.service.LeaderboardJobManagerImpl.lambda$1(LeaderboardJobManagerImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at com.dangalgames.leaderboard.service.LeaderboardJobManagerImpl.lambda$0(LeaderboardJobManagerImpl.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onNext(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2058)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:368)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:276)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BaseSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:439)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:784)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:732)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drainLoop(FluxCreate.java:240)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:206)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:197)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.lambda$recurseCursor$4(BatchCursorFlux.java:98)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$sinkToCallback$30(MongoOperationPublisher.java:549)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.next(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursor.lambda$next$0(BatchCursor.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4515)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4232)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.recurseCursor(BatchCursorFlux.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.lambda$subscribe$0(BatchCursorFlux.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber.onNext(LambdaMonoSubscriber.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:165)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$sinkToCallback$30(MongoOperationPublisher.java:549)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.OperationExecutorImpl.lambda$execute$2(OperationExecutorImpl.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier$RetryingCallback.onResult(RetryingAsyncCallbackSupplier.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.AsyncCallbackSupplier.lambda$whenComplete$1(AsyncCallbackSupplier.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$2.onResult(FindOperation.java:762)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$transformingReadCallback$10(CommandOperationHelper.java:329)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:280)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:687)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:526)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:503)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:815)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:782)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:650)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:250)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:158)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:562)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:277)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:298)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$AsynchronousSocketChannelAdapter.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream.readAsync(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:118)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream.readAsync(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$600(InternalStreamConnection.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:772)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:757)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:650)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:647)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:250)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:191)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting ':' but found ')'.
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:191)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readString(AbstractBsonReader.java:456)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:80)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:31)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:360)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235)
        ... 129 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a name but found '{'.
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:186)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readString(AbstractBsonReader.java:456)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:80)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:31)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:360)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235)
        ... 126 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting ':' but found 'longestStreak'.
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:191)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readString(AbstractBsonReader.java:456)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:80)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:31)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:360)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235)
        ... 123 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON input. Position: 88. Character: '='.
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.JsonScanner.nextToken(JsonScanner.java:118)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.popToken(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:732)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingJsonReader.readBsonType(ParameterBindingJsonReader.java:171)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:679)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readString(AbstractBsonReader.java:456)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:80)
        at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:31)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.readValue(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:360)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.util.json.ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.decode(ParameterBindingDocumentCodec.java:235)
        ... 120 common frames omitted
```

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61efcb757995cb2a0a408ca4"),
    "userId" : UUID("ae45122e-3bb8-40cf-af59-7362ecfa4d1e"),
    "username" : "testUser1",
    "userAvatar" : "test avatar",
    "game" : 8,
    "rake" : 43.0,
    "win" : -5121.0,
    "entryFee" : 34.0,
    "score" : 56,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2022-01-25T10:05:41.725Z")
}
```

Comment: If you add some example document we may attept  some solution without the custom js function which seems to cause some trouble...

Comment: @R2D2 This is the document. The objective of the query is to find the losing streak of a player i.e. max number of continuous games a user lost.
`
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61efcb757995cb2a0a408ca4"),
    "userId" : UUID("ae45122e-3bb8-40cf-af59-7362ecfa4d1e"),
    "username" : "testUser1",
    "userAvatar" : "test avatar",
    "game" : 8,
    "rake" : 43.0,
    "win" : -5121.0,
    "entryFee" : 34.0,
    "score" : 56,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2022-01-25T10:05:41.725Z")}
`

Comment: check here @Alex Blex provided interesting replacement solution for your JS function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876159/mongodb-aggregation-get-max-number-of-negative-sequence-in-array/70879354#70879354      test here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z4HaGQ66nAt

Comment: Thanks, will check this

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question -
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/#syntax says:

> body   String or Code

`Code` works in the shell or nodejs driver. "String" is the only option for drivers on other languages. Wrap the body in quotes like this:

```
"{ $addFields: { losingStreak : { $function: { "
        + "body: \"function(docs) { "
        + "let longestStreak = 0; "
        + "let currentStreak = 0; "
        + "docs.forEach(element => { "
        + "if(element.win < 0) { "
        + "currentStreak = currentStreak + 1; "
        + "if(longestStreak < currentStreak) { "
        + "longestStreak = currentStreak; "
        + "}  "
        + "} else { "
        + "currentStreak = 0;  "
        + "}  });"
        + " return longestStreak;  "
        + "}\", "
```

Please be aware about performance impact and security concerns. It's very much recommended to do not use functions at any cost.

In this particular case I would recommend pre-aggregation. Apply the same logic at insert time once per document and store the result in the document itself, rather than run this function on every query for all documents.

Comment: Thanks, will check