# mongodb aggregation get max number of negative sequence in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I need to get the max count of negative sequence from array via aggregation , example documents:

```
  {
  "id": 1,
   x: [ 1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
 },
 {
"id": 2,
  x: [ 1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1 ]
 }
```

expected result:

```
 {"id": 1,x:4},
 {"id": 2,x:2}
```

Please, advice?

Comment: I think x for id 1 is 6, while x for id 2 is 3?

Comment: no , I need max sequence , so in id:1 , there is two negative sequences 2 & 4 and I need 4 , for id:2 there is only 2 & 1 and the  max  negative sequence is 2  ,

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. So you want to get the max number of **consecutive** negative numbers.

Comment: exactly , but could not find solution yet , and do not want to use additional js functions only pure mongo , I suppose could be something very simple with sum+cond but dont know how to do ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to iterate the array and [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to apply your logic (consecutive negatives)

The carrier is in format

```
     {
        previous: // previous value to compare for continuity 
        acc: // number of consecutive negatives in the current sequence
        max: // length of the longest sequence
      }
```

[$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) is to memoise current accumulator to reuse in the max calculation. It's optional yet convenient:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "x": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$x",
          "initialValue": {
            previous: 0,
            acc: 0,
            max: 0
          },
          "in": {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                result: {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                      "$and": [
                        {
                          "$lt": [
                            "$$this",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "$lt": [
                            "$$value.previous",
                            0
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "then": {
                      "$add": [
                        "$$value.acc",
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    "else": {
                      "$cond": {
                        "if": {
                          "$lt": [
                            "$$this",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        "then": 1,
                        "else": 0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              in: {
                previous: "$$this",
                acc: "$$result",
                max: {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                      $gt: [
                        "$$value.max",
                        "$$result"
                      ]
                    },
                    "then": "$$value.max",
                    "else": "$$result"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      x: "$x.max"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LP0e3ppgOtt).

Comment: Impressive,thanks!  Attempting to help @Ritika Agrawal in this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852923/use-function-javascript-in-mongo-repository-aggregation-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment125294590_70852923

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it.  The general idea is to `$reduce` the sequence to a string and then `$split` to make an array filled with strings of each run.  Then map the array of strings to an array of string lengths and then take the max.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "id": 1,
    "x": {
      "$max": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            $split: [
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$x",
                  "initialValue": "",
                  "in": {
                    $concat: [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "$cond": [
                          {
                            "$gt": [
                              "$$this",
                              0
                            ]
                          },
                          "p",
                          "n"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "p"
            ]
          },
          "in": {
            "$strLenBytes": "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7LgWGfB2gZ4).

Comment: Also works , thanks!